# Using appscript to retrieve multiple rows of information and display it within a panel?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use this script to retrieve multiple pieces of information from the spreadsheet. My goal is to have it look, but skip the cell it already retrieved its information from:

```
function doGet() { 
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('When Am I Eligible?');
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setHeight("400px;").setWidth("800px");
//var submitButton = app.createButton('Check');


var key= '-----'
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET');
   var last=ss.getLastRow();
  var data=sh.getRange(1,1,last,5).getValues();
  var valB= Session.getEffectiveUser();
   var nn = 0;
   for (cnt=0; cnt<8; ++cnt){
 var nn = (nn+1)
  for(var nn;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][1]==valB){
      var final = data[nn][0];
      var final1 = data[nn][1];
      var final2 = data[nn][2];
      var final3 = data[nn][3];
      var final4 = data[nn][4];






      break} ;// if a match in column B is found, break the loop
      }





 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

 var answer = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final)
 var answer1 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final1)
 var answer2 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final2)
  var answer3 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final3)
    var answer4 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final4)
 panel.add(answer).add(answer1).add(answer2).add(answer3).add(answer4);
 app.add(panel);


     if (cnt == 7) {
       break}
   }
  return app;
}
```

Is there any way to do this, my counter is not working to save the place, i've tried `++nn` 'making a new variable etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have the outer loop with the variable `cnt` . Also, not sure why you have (re)declared `nn` thrice. 
I think you could do with a simple loop if all you have to match is column B. Something like

```
for(var nn = 1; nn < data.length ; n++){
  if (data[nn][1] == valB){
    var final = data[nn][0];
    var final1 = data[nn][1];
    var final2 = data[nn][2];
    var final3 = data[nn][3];
    var final4 = data[nn][4];

    /* Update the UI */
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setHeight("400px;").setWidth("800px");
    var answer = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final)
    var answer1 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final1)
    var answer2 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final2)
    var answer3 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final3)
    var answer4 = app.createLabel("BRO").setVisible(true).setText(final4)
    panel.add(answer).add(answer1).add(answer2).add(answer3).add(answer4);
    app.add(panel);
  }
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is using this script to pull data with the same identifier `valB`. There are multiple instances with this identifier. My goal is to display all those instances. I attempted to do this with the cnt variable, but instead it just repeats the first instance 7 times. 

I then tried to make `nn` incremented with each loop, but that hasn't worked so far.

Comment: See the edited answer. All you have to do is move the UI code into your loop.

Comment: That does the same things as my original script. It repeats the data.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand, basically there are 7 records. This script pullls the first one 7 times. I want it to be able to grab the one after the one it just pulled. This way, all the records can be shown. Also, i'm not sure what this is refrencing `n++`. I've used `++nn'.